# User control DP hide button_click

Tags: c#, wpf

I implemented a usercontrol with a simple button_click callback function.
in addition I implemented a DP which set StackPanel with an image to button's content.
When I use the usercontrol without the DP the button_click work just fine, but when I use the DP the button_click callback function isn't called any more...
Anyone know why is that? and how to fix it?
**I know I can implement setting the Image in many other ways but I want to stick with this method(this project is only a study for other project)

User control xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ButtonClick"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="50" Height="40" Background="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

cs user control file:

```
public partial class ButtonClick : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowImageDP = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowImage", typeof(string), typeof(ButtonClick), new PropertyMetadata(null, new PropertyChangedCallback(SetImage)));

        private string      m_strSourceImage    = string.Empty;
        private BitmapImage m_oImage            = null;


        public ButtonClick()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string ShowImage
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(ShowImageDP);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ShowImageDP, value);
            }
        }

        private static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            //Amit: Recive the path string to the Image file.
            ButtonClick l_oBC = (ButtonClick)obj;
            l_oBC.m_strSourceImage = (string)args.NewValue;
            //Amit: If the file exsit read it to BitmapImage.
            if (File.Exists(l_oBC.m_strSourceImage ))
            {
                l_oBC.m_oImage = new BitmapImage(new Uri(l_oBC.m_strSourceImage, UriKind.Absolute));
            }
            //Amit: Build an Image object out of the BitmapImage, set the image to a stack panle and set the panle to the button's content.
            Image l_oImage = new Image();
            l_oImage.Source = l_oBC.m_oImage;
            StackPanel l_oPanle = new StackPanel();
            l_oPanle.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
            l_oPanle.Children.Add(l_oImage);
            l_oBC.Content = l_oPanle;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("We just clicked!");
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please, never ever create any `UIElement`s in the code. That's totally against the WPF idea. Use XAML, MVVM and triggers instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you set the content of the entire usercontrol and not just the button. So the button is completely removed from the window.

So if you give the button a name like this:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Width="50" Height="40"...
```

.. you should be able to set the content in the DP like this:

```
l_oBC.btn.Content = l_oPanle;
```

Comment: Many many thanks!
I couldn't wish for more, both explanation and a solution.
:)